# Second Order Correction to the Perturbative Approximation of the Transition Amplitudes in RQM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, perturbation-theory, regularization

I am studying Relativistic Quantum Mechanics from my professor's notes. When calculating the second order perturbative correction to the transition coefficient $T_{fi}$* in a scattering process by a potential of finite duration, the following term appears

$$\sum_{n\neq i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{i(E_f-E_n)t}\int_{-\infty}^tdt'e^{i(E_f-E_n)t'}.$$

My professor notes that the $dt'$ integral does not make sense unless we interpret it as an expression of the form

$$\lim_{ε\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^tdt'e^{i(E_f-E_n-iε)t'}.$$

I understand why the integral expression does not make sense as well as why the interpretation does, but I would really appreciate any physical reasoning for acting so, any indication as to what might gone wrong in the formulation of the derivation**
and more than anything, any mathematical arguments for why this is alright (for example something indication that this is the only way of giving meaning to such troublesome expressions).

*With this I mean the long time value the coefficient of the the f state of a wave function which purely on the i state before the potential is turned on.

**Which is not presented here, but I hope that it is a standard one and that it is more or less given away (to someone familiar with the subject) by the notation and the results. If not, please ask me to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggle with this concept as well, although I have found some comfort in casual functions.

You're given

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}dt' e^{i w t'} =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' \theta(t-t') e^{i w t'} = e^{i w t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' \theta(-t') e^{i w t'}  = e^{i w t} \tilde{f}_{-}(w)$$

which calls for the fourier transform of a theta function, which I'm preemptively calling $\tilde{f}_{-}(w)$, to be defined below. In classical analysis such an integral does not exist, so I will appeal to distribution theory, defining both $f(t') = 1$ and $f_{-}(t')=\theta(-t') f(t')$, where $f_{-}(t')$ is called the advanced part of $f(t')$. Causality comes in to play when splitting functions into advanced and retarded parts, which have poles exclusively above and below the real axis, respectively.

Then take a laplace transform

$$F[z] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' e^{i z t'} f_{-}(t')$$

which has nicer convergence properties due to the imaginary frequency $z$. Since $f_{-}$ is causal, one can show the relation

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F[w - i\epsilon] = \tilde{f}_{-}(w)$$

where the limit is a distribution limit and I have not bothered tracking overall signs. From here

$$e^{i w t} \tilde{f}_{-}(w) = e^{i w t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' e^{i (w-i\epsilon) t'} f_{-}(t') = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' e^{i (w-i\epsilon) t'} f_{-}(t'-t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' \theta(t-t') e^{i (w-i\epsilon) t'}$$

which is the desired result given $w = E_f - E_n$. Hopefully this offers some insight into how what your professor has does is more than just inserting a convergence factor and is in fact necessary in order to preserve the causal structure of your theory.

Comment: This actually looks very helpful, but I need some clarification. At first glance I got a bit confused by thinking $f_-(ω)$ and $f_-(t)$ to be the same function. Now I am only confused about the definition of $f_-(ω)$. Do you define it to be $lim_{ε\to 0^+} F[ω-iε]$? If so, then why is this it not defined using any other path approaching $ω$ from the negative imaginary part half-plane? Or is it the whole point that this limit is the same for all such ways of approaching ω?

Comment: *...why is it not defined...

Comment: I've edited the text to include $\tilde{f}$ when I want to speak of the fourier transform of $f$, I was abusing notation when distinguishing the two by their arguments and I hope this alleviates some confusion.

Comment: Since we're approaching the real line from below, which is the region of analyticity, I suspect there is some freedom of path, however I'm only familiar with this particular equality.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. Referencing causal functions and distribution limits is comforting enough.